# max possible product of a list with any elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematical-optimization

I have made below function for the same. but it is failing a particular test case I cant know what the input is. What would be a possible input list this function is failing to return max product?
The input will be list of numbers and output should be the max possible product by taking any numbers from list so that product would be max.

```
def max_prod(xs):
  negl = []
  nego = []
  pos = []
  prod = 1
  # if any positive integer greater than 1, then dont need to consider negative integers between -1 and 0
  if any(i for i in xs if i >= 1):
    for i in xs :
      if i <= -1 : nego.append(i)
      elif i > 1 : pos.append(i)
    if  len(nego) % 2 == 1 :
      nego.remove(max(nego))
    for  i in pos : prod = prod * i
    for j in nego : prod = prod * j
    return str(prod)
  
  #if there is no positive integer greater than or equal to 1, 
  else :
    l = []
    for i in xs :
      if i > 0 : pos.append(i)
    if len(pos) != 0 : l.append(max(pos))
    for i in xs :
      if i <= -1  :
        nego.append(i)
      elif i < 0  and i > -1 :
        negl.append(i)
    # if there is only one negative integer lesser than -1
    if len(nego) == 1 :
      if len(negl) == 0:
        return str(0)
      else :
        l.append((nego[0] * min(negl)))
        return str(max(l))
    # if multiple integers lesser than -1
    else :
      if len(nego) >= 1 and len(nego) % 2 == 1 :
        nego.remove(max(nego))
      for  i in nego : prod = prod * i
      return str(prod)
```

Comment: Share the link to the question, if you are doing some CP question. That would help us give out the best optimized result for you

Comment: This is a practise question but the link is not shareble unfortunately. Also I am not asking for a solution but a possible test case that is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post request corner cases where the posted code doesn't work.

Code provides incorrect answers for single negative numbers.

Examples:

```
print(max_prod([0]))
# Output: 1
```

The answer should be 0

Simple fix would be to add condition:

```
if xs == [0]:
    return 0
```

**Simpler Code**

```
from math import prod

def max_prod(xs):
  pos = [i for i in xs if i > 0]
  neg = [i for i in xs if i < 0]

  if len(neg) % 2:
    neg.remove(max(neg))  
    
  if len(pos) > 0 or len(neg) > 0:
    return str(prod(pos) * prod(neg))

  return "0"
```

**Tests**

```
for xs in [[], [0], [2], [-2], [2, 3], [0, 2, 3], 
           [-2, -3], [-2, -3, -4], [2, 0, -2, -3], 
           [2, 0, -2, -3, -1]]:
  print(f'{xs} max-> {max_prod(xs)}')
```

**Output**

```
[] max-> 0
[0] max-> 0
[2] max-> 2
[-2] max-> 0
[2, 3] max-> 6
[0, 2, 3] max-> 6
[-2, -3] max-> 6
[-2, -3, -4] max-> 12
[2, 0, -2, -3] max-> 12
[2, 0, -2, -3, -1] max-> 12
```

Comment: there is no way I can find out test cases. and -5will not be correct answer as we can just ignore it return 0 instead. 0 being greater than -5.

Comment: @anon-bee-01--does the problem state you can take zero elements?  I solved this problem once before (believe it was on Hackerrank) and there a requirement was you had to take at least one element in the product.

Comment: there are no conditions on taking n elements. only expectation is to return a max product.

Comment: @anon-bee-01--the closest post I can find is this problem on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-subarray/) where they're looking for a subarray rather than subsequence.  But, here you see they state it must have at least one element.  Can you provide a link to your question source?

Comment: @anon-bee-01--updated my answer with a case where the code provides the incorrect answer, even allowing for empty subsequence.

Comment: thanks. I will run with this one against test cases to check if this was the problem in my code.

Comment: @anon-bee-01--any update on whether that was the problem?

Comment: @DarryIG it was same as you mentioned, it should return the single negative element.